# Как дать группе пользователей собственные кастомные разрешения

Tags: django, permissions

У меня есть таблица разрешений

```
 edit_user = 'edit_user'
 view_all = 'view_all'
 create_user = 'create_user'
 delete_user = 'delete_user'
 add_user = 'add_user'
 permissions_choice = [
    (edit_user, 'Can edit user '),
    (view_all, 'Can view all'),
    (create_user, 'Can create user'),
    (delete_user, 'Can delete user'),
    (add_user, 'Can add user'),
 ]
```

Вот моя модель

```
from django.db import models
from ..account.models import User
from .consts import *


class Perm(models.Model):
    user_perm = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                              blank=True, related_name='user_perm')
    choices_perm = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=permissions_choice, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return f"{self.user_perm} {self.choices_perm}"

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user_perm', 'choices_perm']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Разрешения'
        verbose_name = 'Разрешение'
```

Нужно что бы каждый пользователь находящийся в группе получал такие же разрешения как и у группы. Как это сделать??

Comment: Группы дефолтные,джанговские?

Comment: Или у тебя группа=Perm?

Comment: Группы дефолтные. а Perm это User и разрешения его

Comment: Просто добавить юзера в группу и дать пермишны с админки самой группе?

Comment: Пермишены кастомные. Админка о них не знает

Comment: А зачем создавать кастомную модель пермишенов? В джанге уже есть для этого модель. Вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816454/django-check-and-set-permissions-for-a-user-group

Comment: Да, я тоже задаюсь этим вопросом... Но увы.

Comment: Это пример плохой архитектуры. Советую переделать, пока не поздно.

Comment: Понял,спасибо. я там обновил вопрос по формам